# YooTheme Zoo Application Blog Front Page

Tags: joomla, pagination

I am using YooTheme's ZOO Blog application on my front page. I have two things I'd like to acheive;

- When clicking on an article title, you are taken to a page where you
  have the article in full view, including any read-more content you
  may/may not have. When taken to this page, you still have all modules
  which are assigned to the 'home' menu item. Unfortunately, in order
  for the application, 'Blog' to show on the front page - it must be
  assigned to the 'home' menu item.

I'd preferably like the full article page just to have the menu module at the top, and perhaps any modules I do actually 'enable'.

- A strange one - I'd like to have no pagination at the bottom of my
  front page. I'd simply like to encourage users to go to a separate
  page that lists all of the news.

I hope someone can help!

I'd utilise the 'fantastic' community that YooTheme holds - but unfortunately, after 3 months (being the lowest tier when you buy a product) any and -all- support stops. This includes the ticketing system which is mainly community-help based.

If need be, I can provide screen shots.

Comment: Seeing as this is a commercial extension which I doubt not even a handful of people on here will have and be experienced with, you would be better off contacting the Yootheme developers. Their support is very good.

Comment: They'll only support you if you buy a new 3 month license. It's pretty rubbish :/

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the full and any layout by clicking to the icon in zoo administrator panel. There you can edit every element in the link which is under your app type name! Next to the "Default" or your template there are links for full, teaser, feed etc. Full is for the full view of the item and teaser is for the category/front page view! In Yootheme's website you can find a comprehensive documentation about zoo also! Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers to this problem. (I'm not native english speaker, but I hope you'll understand)

**First method** - sh404sef, I don't know whether it's a feature or a bug in that component, but that what you need to do:

1. Unpublish your default homepage menu item(zoo category for example) to wich there were assigned modules that you dont need to be shown, then create and make it Default Page(star sign) new menu item(or use existing one), and assign to it the modules that you want to appear in the full item view(I'm using product not a blog zoo app) or article full view when you click link from homepage and opens zoo item page or zoo  category page.
2. In joomla Globa Configuration turn on - Use URL rewriting, then in sh404sef Control Panel turn on - Enable URL optimization and Rewriting mode with .htaccess . Errase all the url links in sh404SEF: URL manager(if any exist), we need it (sh404SEF) to create new links.
3. Now when you open new default home page with modules you need to be shown in the zoo item full view, you start to going on ALL the zoo links you wish to open then with that quantity of modules. sh404sef creates SEF link in it backend (in URL manager). And that links will open with exactly with that quantity of modules with zoo.
4. Now you can publish back again your previos homepage and make it default page. And there will be modules that you want on homepage, but because of links that sh404sef created when you were clicking, the zoo items or article links will open with different modules that we asigned to our second default page you use to create those links. For that purpose I commonly use existing menu item where will be another set of modules not like in the homepage. When you have new link on site you have to partially repeat that. You have to go on that link first time from the page where quantity of modules suits you (and to be on the safe side make that page your default page for that time)

**Second method**  - JoomlaXTC Zoo Item Wall, its a module you don't have to make menu item to show zoo items on a homepage. But, I didn't tried it myself I only read about it.